# idle proccesses and high memory bad? uwsgi/django

Tags: linux, memory, django, uwsgi

I have a VPS with 256MB of ram. I'm running nginx, uwsgi and postgresql on Ubuntu 12.04 for a soon to be Django site. About 200MB of ram are being used despite the website not being active, the uwsgi processes seem to just be idling. Is this bad? I once heard that having a bunch of free memory isn't necessarily a good metric because it is possible that the memory in use can easily be freed up. I mean, it is possible that the server is storing commonly used "stuff" in case it is accessed but is more than happy to dump it if the ram is needed. But I'm really not sure, hence me asking this question. If it is bad I could set some of the application loading options for uwsgi like "cheap" or "idle" mode.

[Screenshot of my htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUvBc.jpg)

Edit: Since I'm sitting at a -2 and an answer that doesn't address what I asked, I'm also open to advice on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

256 MB of RAM is *not* nearly enough memory for an application like that. You will run into problems even with a small amount of traffic.